# SQL Server rendering data in json, react, node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server

Backend code example: I am trying to get users here from my SQL Server database `Account`:

```
async function executeQuery() {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const result = await pool
      .request()
      .query(`USE Account SELECT TOP 10 UserNo FROM UserTable`);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

app.get("/api/data", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await executeQuery();
  res.json(result);
});
```

React frontend code: I am getting an error when try to render data from SQL Server.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function SqlTest() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData() {
    const result = await fetch("/api/data").then((res) => res.json());
    setData(result);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.UserNo}>{item.UserNo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SqlTest;
```

I am trying to render data from SQL Server, but nothing helps..

[image]

Comment: Do you have 2 projects, one React and one NodeJS Express?  Also, did you create this using CRA?  Or Vite?  Or something else?

Comment: Node js and react yes i used CRA

Answer (score -1):

Ok, your problem is a very common one that has a very common solution.

You have 2 separate projects (HTTP servers):

1. The HTTP server that **CRA** comes with, which is a NodeJS server.
2. Your API server, which happens to also be a NodeJS server.

Now you want to fetch data from React by querying your API server.

Look at your URL:  `api/data`.  This is a **relative** URL.  Relative URL's are resolved by the browser by using the current page's domain.  I don't know your exact setup, but the URL will end up being something like `http://localhost:3000/api/data`.

Do you see the problem already?  Your API server is not listening on port 3000.  It is probably listening on some other port number.  After all, no 2 applications can listen on the same TCP port.

So you would then be tempted to change your fetch URL to a full URL that specifies the server API:  `http://localhost:3001/api/data`.  That probably works, but there's a chance it errors out due to **CORS**.

So long story short, do as the **CRA** help pages say you should do:  Set a proxy up in your CRA server.  Here it is:  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

In a nutshell, create the file `src/setupProxy.js` with code similar to this:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000', // <-- USE YOUR API PORT
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

The sample assumes you're running your API server in port 5000.  Change it to fit your configuration.

Comment: ```testsql.js:7 GET http://localhost:3000/api/data net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
fetchData @ testsql.js:7
``` getting now this

Comment: I don't know your port numbers.  Use your port numbers.  I don't have that information, you do.

Comment: i use 3000 for react and port 80 for node